# Tag key cannot be updated by your account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloud9

Trying to deploy using `sam deploy` from cloud9 environment shows the following error

```
Deploying with following values
    ===============================
    Stack name                 : aws-cloud9-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx
    Region                     : eu-west-2
    Confirm changeset          : False
    Deployment s3 bucket       : None
    Capabilities               : ["CAPABILITY_IAM"]
    Parameter overrides        : {'ECRDockerImageArn': 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/chimerecording:latest'}

Initiating deployment
=====================

Command sam failed with exit code 1 signal null
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: aws-cloud9-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx, An error 
occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: aws:cloud9:environment 
tag key cannot be updated by your account.
```

The IAM user has the policies,
[image]

What is wrong with this, Do we need to attach any policy with this user?

Comment: The credentials you are using to update the stack have permissions to update the tag on that resource's type?

Comment: @CastroRoy I am not sure about that, I have added these policies, Do we need to enable any other settings for this?

Comment: You will need to check in each of those policies to see if the permissions to update the tag on the resource you are trying to update exists.